# Indexing in multi-tenant application spring data mongo

Tags: spring, mongodb, indexing, spring-data-mongodb, multi-tenant

I am using spring data mongo in a multi tenant application, I have a document class **@Document** where I have used Annotation **@Indexed** to create indexing on the field.
When I start my application with default tenant then collection is created automatically in mongo db with indexing on the field which is fine,

Then, I create new tenant at runtime with different schema and hit my API, the collection is created dynamically in the new schema but there is no indexing.

**In short, if collection is created while starting the application, @Indexed Annotation works but if collection is creating dynamically then Index is not creating.**

What can be the solution for this scenario were collections are creating dynamically?

Comment: Why don't create an index as while creating a collection?

Comment: It is created dynamically when we try to store data on that collection for the first time. Spring Data Mongo created collection dynamically if its not there.